# Java 10 NumberFormat fails to parse a double in exponential format

Tags: java, java-10

I have recently upgraded from Java 8 to Java 10.  I have come across a failing test using Java 10 which I am not sure how to handle.  We have some code that is parses `String` representation of double values into double values using `java.text.NumberFormat.getInstance()`.  In the cases where the value is written in exponential form, the parsed value is incorrect when using Java 10.

Here's my JUnit test:

```
@Test
public void testMe() throws ParseException {
    String input = "2.0E-4";
    double output = NumberFormat.getInstance().parse(input).doubleValue();
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

When using Java 8, the double variable is correctly set to 0.0002:

[image: Screenshot of Java 8 run]

When using Java 10, the double value is incorrectly set to 2.0:

[image: Screenshot of Java 10 run]

Does anyone know if this is an intentional change on Java's part?

---

It seems like `Double.valueOf()` parses it correctly, though.

Comment: [Don't post images of code.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1553851)

Comment: Really?  Helpful.  Happy to provide the code, but I'm also showing the output of the test

Comment: Yes, please include the code as text.

Comment: If you read the docs from [SE8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String)) and then read the docs from [SE10](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String)) you'll see that the description for parse changed. If you read carefully it now says ***"The method may not use the entire text of the given string"***. 
So it seems that it was an intentional change

Comment: ^^ sadly that doesn't answer your question but hopefully a poke in the right direction

Comment: Hmm, that line about not using the entire text is in the Java 8 doco as well... but I'll look more closely at the doco for parse :/

Comment: Prints [2.0E-4 on Java 10 as well](https://tio.run/##y0osS9TNSsn@/7@gNCknM1khOSexuFjBNzEzT6GaixMqWFySWAKkyvIzUxRygVIawSVFmXnp0bEKiUXpxZoglZzBlcUlqbl6@aUlegVAyZKcPA0lj9ScnHwdhfD8opwURSVNay7OWq7a//8B) for me. Any significant change that you might have brought in?

Comment: That's all the code.  We're using OpenJDK 10.0.1... which JDK are you using?  It's also OpenJDK 10.0.1 on Windows 10

Comment: What I've done is stop using the NumberFormat for this part of the logic.  I can achieve the same goal by using Double.parseDouble to read the double value from a String.  The implementation of parseDouble has changed between Java 8 and 10 (from sun.misc.FloatingDecimal to jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal) but by calling at the Double level I'm happily unaware of that.  I'm still not sure if this change was intentional, but I can use a different Java class to get what I want consistently across versions

Comment: Do you understand that `NumberFormat.getInstance()` returns a **localized** format?

Comment: @nullpointer might work for your, resp. tio’s locale, surely doesn’t work on my locale, even with Java 8. The first step to understand the problem, is to understand that `NumberFormat.getInstance()` return the number format *for the current locale* (and we don’t know the OP’s locale). Then, as numerous date parsing questions on SO show, local format definitions may change. Even the set of supported locales may change, so perhaps the OP’s language wasn’t supported in Java 8, that’s why parsing the en_us format worked there, but is supported in Java 10, so it expects the actual local format now…

Comment: @Holger Agreed and I guess the direction you are pointing to is http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/252 in that case.

Comment: Just to fill in the gaps, my Locale is en_AU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From JDK 9 onwards, the default locale data uses data derived from the Unicode Consortium's Common Locale Data Repository (CLDR). So there are changes with respect to some locales in Java 9 and later. Refer the release notes of [Java 9](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/9-relnote-issues-3704069.html#JDK-8008577) and the corresponding [JEP 252](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/252).

Refer the [exponential symbol](https://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/29/by_type/numbers.symbols.html#94ee7e80488e1a0) at the CLDR number symbols chart, for `en_AU` the exponential symbol is `e` (lower case) rather than `E` (upper case). Hence, the difference in output.

```
String input = "2.0e-4";
double output = NumberFormat.getInstance().parse(input).doubleValue();
System.out.println(output);
```

will give the expected output :

```
java version "10.0.1" 2018-04-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10, mixed mode)
2.0E-4
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  That makes sense.  I get the same outcome in my tests